# Unit/Feature test in Laravel returns 500 in browser works fine

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

I am working on writing tests for the first time.

```
public function a_user_can_see_the_service_form()
{
    $response = $this->get('/service');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertSeeText('Details of the serviceman/woman');
    $response->assertSeeText('Save and continue');
}
```

This is my test and this is controller function it calls,

```
    public function serviceChoiceSave(ServiceChoiceSave $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
//      if(null === $request->session()->get('reference')) {
//          $request->session()->put('reference', $this->_createReference($request->input('service')));
//      }

        $request->session()->put('service', $request->input('service'));
        //dd($request->session()->get('service'));
        return redirect('/service/death-in-service');
    }
```

Basically the controller takes the POST and puts it in the session, in my test I get the following error,

> Expected status code 302 but received 500.

and in my logs I get,

> [2019-07-02 11:47:24] local.ERROR: Session store not set on request. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Session store not set on request.

Can anyone tell me why, as it works fine when I run the application in my browser.

Comment: is `<env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>` inside your phpunit.xml?

Comment: Check [testing with session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests#session-and-authentication)

Comment: @RolandStarke yep

Comment: How to run these test codes?

Comment: the serviceChoiceSave method is post http method? and within your test you have  $this->get('/service'), update your controller code in this question, you are misunderstanding how to test